# How can i replicate data with a sql method

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to copy data. But I uses 2 databases on my application. But when I copy that data I need to insert a new row with the same data. Only I dont know how to do that.

I have already tried somethings so I tried to replicate that data and then the relations but that didnt work for me. So I ask one of my friends and he say you need to use a insert into method.

```
public function copySurvey( Manager $fractal, SurveyTransformer $surveyTransformer ) {

    // Copy function (Alleen nog niet volledig hier nog even aanwerken.)
    $original = Survey::first();

    $new = $original->replicate();
    $new->sid = 123456;
    $new->save();

    foreach($original->groups as $group){

    }

    foreach($original->questions as $question){
        $new->questions()->attach($question);
    }
}
```

my model:

```
  public function accuracy() {

    return $this->hasOne( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Accuracy', 'survey_id', 'sid' );
}

public function groups() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Group', 'sid', 'sid' )->orderBy('gid', 'asc')->orderBy('group_order', 'asc');
}

public function questions() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Question', 'sid', 'sid' )->orderBy('gid', 'asc')->orderBy('question_order', 'asc');
}

public function parentQuestions() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Question', 'sid', 'sid' )->where('parent_qid', '=', 0)->orderBy('gid', 'asc')->orderBy('question_order', 'asc');
}

public function languages() {

    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\LimeSurvey\Language', 'surveyls_survey_id', 'sid' );
}
```

Comment: the two database are on the same mysql server ??

Comment: No they stay on a different mysql server. In phpmyadmin can i selected they servers and switch between the servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described two types of relations in your model:

- 1x HasOne (Accuracy)
- 4x HasMany (groups, questions, parentQuestions and languages)

#### HasOne relations

You need to copy the related Accuray. That's easy, and you only of to copy the model like you did for the survey.

```php
$original = Survey::first();

// Firstly, clone the survey
$new = $original->replicate();
$new->sid = 123456;
$new->save(); // This is fine

// The clone the accuracy, and attach it to the cloned survey
$originalAccuracy = $original->accuracy;
$newAccuracy = $originalAccuracy->replicate();
$newAccuracy->survey_id = $new->sid;
$newAccuracy->save();
```

#### HasMany relations

You need to copy every related models, one by one. I suggesst doing the following:

```php
$original = Survey::first();

$new = $original->replicate();
$new->sid = 123456;
$new->save(); // This is fine

/*
 * Example for groups
 * For each group related with the original survey, we create a clone group, and attach it to the new survey.
 */
$original->groups()->get()->each(function($originalGroup) use ($new) {
    $newGroup = $originalGroup->replicate();
    $newGroup->sid = $new->sid; // Adjust foreign key (in the related table) and local key (in survey table)
    $newGroup->save();
});
```

#### BelongsToMany relations

Edit: You do not seem to need this part, but I will let it if it can help someone.

As you replicate you model, all your relations should be ok, except the Many-to-Many ones.

I suspect that the problem is linked to your usage of the `attach()` function. Taken from the Laravel 5.8 documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

```php
$user = App\User::find(1);
$user->roles()->attach($roleId);
```

As you can see, the **attach function uses the id** of the role.

Moreover, in your case, you want to attach multiple Many-To-Many models. I would do the following:

```php
public function copySurvey( Manager $fractal, SurveyTransformer $surveyTransformer ) {

    // Copy function (Alleen nog niet volledig hier nog even aanwerken.)
    $original = Survey::first();

    $new = $original->replicate();
    $new->sid = 123456;
    $new->save(); // This is fine

    // Assuming groups() and questions() are BelongsToMany relationships
    $new->groups()->attach($original->groups()->get()->pluck("id")->toArray());
    $new->questions()->attach($original->questions()->get()->pluck("id")->toArray());
}
```

Comment: So i have tried this. But Thankyou for take the time. But i get  this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::attach()  i posted my model to the main post

Comment: That's normal, because attach is for a BelongsToMany relation, whereas you seem to use a HasMany relation. In this case, the foreign key is directly bundled in your model, so no additional copy is required.
To be clear: the attach() method is only required if you got a BelongsToMany relation, (the one with a join table)

Comment: @PatrickStek I edited the answer, hope that it will help you!